# postgresql function with list of arrays as input

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want a postgresql function that will take a list of arrays, and loop through them.

I have written a "hello world" type function that takes a single array and prints it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_array(_array varchar[]) RETURNS VOID 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%', _array;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which I can call:
`SELECT print_array('{a,b,c}');`

output:

`{a,b,c}`

How would I extend this function to take a list of n arrays?

Expected input: `SELECT print_arrays('{a,b,c}', '{foo,bar,baz}');`

Expected output:

`{a,b,c}`

`{foo,bar,baz}`

I tried following the examples listed in the docs: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-control-structures.html#:~:text=40.6.5.%20Looping%20Through%20Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-control-structures.html#:%7E:text=40.6.5.%20Looping%20Through%20Arrays)
But I don't know how to define a function with a list of arrays as the input.

Comment: `print_array(_array1 varchar[], _array2 varchar[])`?

Comment: I'd like the function to be able to accept any number of arrays

Comment: See [VARIADIC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked using VARIADIC:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_arrays(VARIADIC _arrays varchar[]) RETURNS VOID 
AS $$
DECLARE
    arr text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH arr IN ARRAY _arrays
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%', arr;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```